# I have installed FreeCAD v0.18 successfully but when tried to upgrade using apt it was failed

Tags: linux, debian

I have installed FreeCAD v0.18 successfully but when tried to upgrade using apt it was failed. I want to install v0.19 or higher but looks like latest version of FreeCAD is not listed in Apt repo so what is the best way to do it?

Also, while upgrading looks like VNC service also broken and not I am not able to connect through VNC server.

```
Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session has failed.
```

I have checked everything on the server and was able to restore the VNC service but if I am trying to connect externally then it's not working but I am able to connect to localhost.

Any idea or suggestions ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us how you checked he available versions. I see version 0.20.2 [is available](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=freecad&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) for Debian, so how exactly did it fail when you tried to install it? What error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install FreeCAD v19 and higher, you have 2 solutions:

1. Installing [freecad v21.1](https://snapcraft.io/freecad) or the development release [freecad-realthunder](https://snapcraft.io/freecad-realthunder) from snap store:

   sudo apt install snapd
   sudo snap install core
   sudo snap install freecad

or the beta:

```
sudo snap install freecad-realthunder
```

2. Upgrade your Debian distribution from Buster to Bullseye FreeCAD v19 is available, or upgrade to Bookworm v20 is available.